How get rid of ghosts or pisachas?
How can one protect oneself from the psychological or physical attack of ghosts or psychic vampires, and also from having bad dreams?

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pishacha

Worship Narasimha.

Thank you @Anu.

There are many prayers / stutis / strotas / chalisa which you can recite to get rid of ghosts.
Hanuman :

Hanuman Chalisa
Bajrang Baan

Ganesh :

Ganesh Chalisa

Vishnu :

Narayan Kavach
Narsimha Kavach

Durga :

Durga Kavach / Chandi Kavach
Durga Chalisa

From Hanuman Chalisa :
Bhut Pisach Nikat Nahi Aave, Mahavir Jab naam Sunave ||
One of the lines from Durga Kavach :
अभिचाराणि सर्वाणि मन्त्रयन्त्राणि भूतले।
भूचराः खेचराश्‍चैव जलजाश्‍चोपदेशिकाः॥४९॥
सहजा कुलजा माला डाकिनी शाकिनी तथा।
अन्तरिक्षचरा घोरा डाकिन्यश्‍च महाबलाः॥५०॥
ग्रहभूतपिशाचाश्‍च यक्षगन्धर्वराक्षसाः।
ब्रह्मराक्षसवेतालाः कूष्माण्डा भैरवादयः ॥५१॥
नश्यन्ति दर्शनात्तस्य कवचे हृदि संस्थिते।
मानोन्नतिर्भवेद् राज्ञस्तेजोवृद्धिकरं परम्॥५२॥
Meaning :
All those, who cast magical spells by mantras or yantras, on others for evil purposes, all bhoots, goblins, malevolent beings moving on the earth and in the sky, all those who mesmerise others, all female goblins, all yakshas and gandharvas are destroyed just by the sight of the person having Kavach in his heart
Have faith in one of the deities / supreme and chant. You will be protected.
